# Really confused about proving is sets are Field.

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory, convex-analysis

We have learned what a set must have to be a feild. But I'm very unsure how to prove one. I'm not sure which rule I should start with. There are 6 rules we learned:

A set F is a field if

1)Closure under addition and multiplication

2) associativity of addition and multiplication

3) commutativity of addition and multiplication

4) additive and multiplicative identity

5) existence of negative and reciprocals

6)distributivity of addition over multiplication

For the following question I see every rule is clear except for rule 1 as 1+ 1/2 = 3/2 which is not in the set F... However I've seen in examples in my textbook that its not necessary that 1 + 1/2 = 3/2 as it could equal any other element in the set. I'm very very confused. Any guidance would be appreciated.

let F be the following set:

$ F = \{...{\pm\frac 1{2^3}}, {\pm\frac 1{2^2}}, {\pm\frac 1{2}}, 0, 1, {\pm{2}}, {\pm2^{2}}, {\pm2^{3}},... \} $

Is this set (with the usual addition and multiplication) a field? Explain

Comment: Regarding "examples in my textbook that its not necessary that 1 + 1/2 = 3/2": to determine whether $F$ is a field you need to know both the set of elements and the operations. In those other examples the addition operation was probably not the usual one, but this question specifies that the operations are "the usual addition and multiplication".

Answer (score 1):

It is not closed under addtion since $1+1+1=3$.

Comment: $1+2=3$ would suffice.